# How can remove Page Title set while loading Page via Ajax?

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, title

I am using Codeigniter 2 with modular extensions. I load all my pages via Ajax Jquery.

I load page like follow:

```
<a href="#Add Products" onclick="addProduct()> Add Product</a>
```

In IE, the title page is set as My Admin Title#Add Products.

How can I remove that post fix in IE title?

I want that My Page Title remains also same, just "My Admin Title".

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. I finally found out the cause but still not able to find proper solution. My page title in IE is changed by Uploadify. Uploadify change page title to "#.." when i click on any page where i have used uploadify. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try different ways to set title with JQuery:

```
$(document).attr('title','Whatever');
```

OR

```
$(document)[0].title = 'Whatever';
```

OR

```
$(document).get(0).title = 'Whatever';
```

Comment: Thank it solved my problem.

but still wondering why uploadify change my title in IE..?????

Answer (score 1):

You can access the title element by doing:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].innerHTML = "My Admin Title";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put something like

```
document.title = "Hello World!";
```

to change the title of the HTML Page, but I am not sure how it work with your extensions.